# Design of convolution kernel CUDA

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpgpu

I am trying to design a convolution kernel code for CUDA. It will take relatively small pictures (typically for my application a 19 * 19 image)

In my research , i found most notably this paper :  https://www.evl.uic.edu/sjames/cs525/final.html

I understand the concept of it, but I wonder, for small images, does using
a block by pixel of the original image, and using the threads of that block as the pixels to fetch , then do a block wide reduction, fast enough ? I made a basic implementation that makes global memory access coalescent, so, is it a good design for small pictures ? Or should I follow the "traditional" method ?

Comment: How big is the kernel?

Comment: The kernel is 15 * 15 or 31 * 31 cells. I pad them to powers of 2, which is what I tried to make the global memory accesses coalesced

Comment: That looks to be small enough that you could load both kernel and image into shared memory with room to spare.

Comment: This is the approach I took, with some tweaks for non divisible image sizes (e.g 9 * 9 with kernel radius = 8, you need to load a picture of (9 + 2 * 8)² px, or 25², so you need to divide between the threads (maybe should I use "dummy" warps so each thread load 1 pixel ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends upon your eventual application for your program. If you intend to only convolute a few "relatively small pictures", as you mention, then a naive approach should be sufficient. In fact, a serial approach may even be faster due to memory transfer overhead between the CPU and GPU if you're not processing much data. I would recommend first writing the kernel which accesses global memory, as you mention, and if you will be working with a larger dataset in the future, it would make sense to attempt the "traditional" approach as well, and compare runtimes.

Comment: Thanks, that guides me. I though of this approach but wanted approval of this method. Thanks deeply

Comment: In the end, event with coalesced conflicts, my try implementation was really slow, except for huges  > 32 * 32 kernels, which makes it kind of unusable, the time scaling by apparently (n / 1024)² or 3.... I leave this comment as a warning for others : *this concept doesn't work, and even for smaller images, the paper got better solutions*